# JHipster prod profile is cleaning resources with auto-clean resulting in 'databse type NONE' error

Tags: jhipster

The auto-clean step in the prod profile is cleaning all the resources and yaml files and when you start the app with the prod profile you get the following error due to no config being in place.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the 
classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular 
profile you may need to active it (the profiles "prod" are currently 
active).
```

[image: maven auto-clean on prod profile]

Comment: The `yml` files are not stored in the `target` folder so I'm not sure how that's related

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the response. Sorry, I should've made it a bit clearer, my bad. Basically, any config is copied to `target` folder as this is how the war file is ultimately built. I found that the `./mvnw -Pprod package` task does an `auto-clean` after the `copy-resources` task, which basically cleans out all the `config` and `resources` from the `target` folder, that would have made its way into the `war`. If there's no config, you can start the app with any profile you want, it finds no config, hence the `database type NONE` error. Or have I got this completely wrong :)

Comment: As far as I know JHipster build does not use auto-clean in generated pom.xml nor in its dependency pom. So I suspect that you have made some changes or added a pom parent which configures this behavior.

Comment: Thanks Gael, I might have an older version. I'll try regenerate a new project and check. Maybe my pom got polluted somehow. I'll verify and advise. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea how on earth this piece of code found its way into my pom, in the `prod` profile. `<executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>auto-clean</id>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>clean</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>`

Comment: I had a look in my git history and it looks like it may have happened at some point during a previous upgrade from 4.12 to 4.13. Bit of a mystery, but at any rate, its definitely not there now. Sorry for the false alarm, it's a bit strange. Thank you for the responses.